# Problem with the generation of csv file with condition

Tags: php, mysql, csv

The following php code allows me to retrieve from a database the information of the orders of the day in order to export them in a csv file.

However I also have a file ArticleStock.csv which contains information on the products: ID and Name but which are different from those present in the database. I found a way to link the two by adding the IDs from the ArticleStock file to the product reference field.

Unfortunately this does not work well because the following program outputs a csv file with only the corresponding value found and not all the others

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $sql = 'SELECT o.id_order ,
                    c.id_customer, c.firstname, c.lastname, 
                    a.address1, a.address2, a.postcode, 
                    a.city,a.phone,
                    c.email,
                    a.phone_mobile, 
                    od.product_id, od.product_name, 
                    p.reference, 
                    od.product_quantity, od.product_price, 
                    o.total_paid_tax_incl, 
                    c.id_customer, 
                    op.date_add, op.amount, op.payment_method
    FROM mod582_orders o
        INNER JOIN mod582_customer c ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer
        INNER JOIN mod582_address a ON o.id_address_delivery = a.id_address
        INNER JOIN mod582_order_detail od ON o.id_order = od.id_order
        INNER JOIN mod582_order_payment op ON o.reference = op.order_reference
        INNER JOIN mod582_product p ON p.id_product = od.product_id
    WHERE CAST(o.date_add AS DATE) like "2022-12%";';

    $r = $pdo->query($sql);
    $tab = [];
    $tab[] = ['ORDNOORDER', 'ORDREFCUSORDER', 'ORDNOCOSTNUMBER', 'ORDNOCUSTOMER', 'ORDCUSTOMERCODE', 'ORDCUSCAT', 'ORDTYPE', 'ORDCURRENCY', 'ORDCURRENCYRATE', 'ORDDESIGNATION',
        'ORDREPCODE', 'ORDPORT', 'ORDPORTTYPE', 'ORDPORTRATE', 'DEONOORDER', 'DEOCOMMENT', 'DEOCOUNTRY', 'DEONAME', 'DEOFIRSTNAME', 'DEOADDRESS1', 'DEOADDRESS2', 'DEOZIPCODE', 'DEOCITY',
        'DEOPHONE', 'DEOMAIL', 'DEOPHONEPORTABLE', 'ODLNOORDER', 'ODLNOORDERLINE', 'ODLNOARTICLE', 'ODLARTDESIGN', 'REFERENCEPRODUIT', 'ODLQUANTITYORDER', 'ODLTTCCURUPRICE', 'ODLCODEPARCELLEFLEU',
        'PAYNUMPAYMENT', 'PAYNOCUSTOMER', 'PAYNOORDER', 'PAYNOCURRENCY', 'PAYDATEPAYMENT', 'PAYPAYMENTTTCCUR', 'PAYCURRENCYRATE', 'PAYCONTREPARTIE'];

    $odrline = 0; // start with zero, as incremented before first written out
    $prevordernumber = 0; // pick a number that is not a valid order number

    $file = fopen("ArticlesStock.csv", "r");
    $rowcsv = 0;
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $thisLine = fgets($file);
        $CSVData[$rowcsv] = explode(";", $thisLine);
        $rowcsv++;
    }
    fclose($file);
    $numRows = sizeof($CSVData);
    $rowcsv = 0;

    while ($rs = $r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $refproduit = $rs['reference'];
        while ($rowcsv < $numRows) {
            if ($CSVData[$rowcsv][0] == $refproduit) {
                $idproduct = $CSVData[$rowcsv][0];
                $nameproduct = $CSVData[$rowcsv][2];

                if ($prevordernumber != $rs['id_order']) {
                    $odrline++;
                    $baseDate = strtotime($rs['date_add']);
                    $formatDate = date("d/m/Y", $baseDate);
                    $tab[] = [$rs['id_order'], $rs['id_order'], '17', '', 'AAA' . $rs['id_customer'], 'DET', 'O', 'EUR', '1', '', '115', 'D', 'P', '17', $rs['id_order'], '', 'FRA', $rs['firstname'],
                        $rs['lastname'], $rs['address1'], $rs['address2'], $rs['postcode'], $rs['city'], $rs['phone'], $rs['email'], $rs['phone_mobile'], $rs['id_order'], $odrline,
                        $idproduct, $nameproduct, $rs['reference'], $rs['product_quantity'], $rs['product_price'], '', '', '', $rs['id_order'], 'EUR', $formatDate, $rs['amount'], '1', 'VIR'];
                } else {
                    $tab[] = [$rs['id_order'], $rs['id_order'], '17', '', 'AAA' . $rs['id_customer'], 'DET', 'O', 'EUR', '1', '', '115', 'D', 'P', '17', $rs['id_order'], '', 'FRA', $rs['firstname'],
                        $rs['lastname'], $rs['address1'], $rs['address2'], $rs['postcode'], $rs['city'], $rs['phone'], $rs['email'], $rs['phone_mobile'], $rs['id_order'], $odrline,
                        $rs['product_id'], $rs['product_name'], $rs['reference'], $rs['product_quantity'], $rs['product_price'], '', '', '', $rs['id_order'], '', '', '', ''];
                }
            }
            $rowcsv++;
        }
        $prevordernumber = $rs['id_order'];
    }

// write $tab to file
    $date = date('d-m-y');
    $fichier_csv = new SplFileObject('Vinistoria/Out/Commande/commande_STOCK_' . $date . '.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($tab as $ligne) {
        $fichier_csv->fputcsv($ligne, ';');
    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
}
```

CSV return by my code :

[image]

And what i need :

[image]

So i need to replace my csv file ODLNOARTICLE and ODLARTDESIGN by the IDs and Names of products present in the file ArticleStock whose ID is equal to the reference field of my products recovered by my SQL query

Comment: Still struggling with this I see

Comment: Ok so The query retrieves data from the following tables:

mod582_orders
mod582_customer
mod582_address
mod582_order_detail
mod582_order_payment
mod582_product
The query joins the tables on specific columns and filters the results to only retrieve data where the "date_add" column in the "mod582_orders" table is like "2022-12%".

Comment: I'm going to work on this and post an answer...

Comment: Didnt I suggest that you load the CSV into your database as a new table *temporary probably" and then you can use it in your query

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, however the ArticleStock file is stored on an ftp and regularly re-uploaded in order to update the quantities of products inside

Comment: SO do the FTP and import as part of this proessing (hence I suggested a Temporary Tabll)